# What fingering to use for Ornithology on piano?

Tags: piano, jazz, fingering

I'm trying to play ornithology on piano and was wondering what fingering would be best for the first line. Whatever I try seems uncomfortable...
Thanks!

[image: ornithology]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "obvious" fingering would be

2 | 1 2 3 4 - 5 3 4 5 4 | 3 1

If you don't like that, you could try starting with your thumb. Then play another note with your thumb under your fingers, so you don't run out of fingers before your get to the top note - i.e.

1 | 2 3 1 4 - 5 3 4 5 4 | 3 1 or

1 | 2 1 3 4 - 5 3 4 5 4 | 3 1

or you might prefer

1 | 2 3 1 3 - 4 2 3 4 3 | 2 1 or

1 | 2 1 2 3 - 4 2 3 4 3 | 2 1

Answer (score 0):

Start with your thumb on the D and then move it up to G and play the rest in that position. It might take a bit of work to transition cleanly, but that is the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the anacrucis D, the first phrase ranges between G and the upper D. All that can be played with thumb on G, up to pinky on D. The easiest seems to be to play the first D and move the whole hand sideways to the new position.